# How to set the media query in css

Tags: css

Please help me use media queries in CSS. How can I set the `min-height` of the input fields in the media query?

I set the form width in media query `300px` for `min-width`.  When I add input tag in the media query and give the width, the input fields won't set.

Please help to set the fields.

This is my media code:

```
@media screen and (min-width:480px){
    form{
        width:300px;
    }
    input{
        width:100px;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you be a bit more clear in your requirements? i don't understand so well...

Comment: Your query works fine. https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/52z0sfgd/3/ So can you show the HTML too? Maybe that's where you have problems.

Comment: What CSS rules do the dev tool's of you browser show being applied to the element? (Most likely some other CSS rule has higher precedence, and thus this rule is being ignored – media queries do not have any additional weighting in the cascade).

Comment: i'm saying that when i use the media query in css for my form that contained form width and input fields. How can i set the form in small devices for example mobile devices etc.

Comment: This is **extremely** *common-knowledge*, did you try googling a tutorial before asking here?

Comment: You probably need to change *min-width: 480px* into *max-width: 480px* to make it work on your mobile device.

Comment: How is this related to `PHP` or `MySQL`? Inspect your input fields in your browser and make sure there is no other class set that overwrites your media query settings

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your css rules does not work because of the HTML, your media query is fine
For example your form is in a `div` if you want to add css to your form you should do :

```
@media screen and (min-width:480px){
    div {
        form {
            width:300px;
        }
    }
}
```